# After boot, my Raspberry Pi reverts to tty1

Tags: raspbian, boot, desktop

On boot my Pi shows the standard Raspbian desktop, but then it switches to tty1 and I have to use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get back to the desktop.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a new install and it's done this from the start, or did it mysteriously just begin one day?

Comment: Install is less than a month old and started doing it after a recent update.

Comment: Related: [Raspbian (Jessie) boots into tty7 then reverts into tty1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/76373/84497)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following commands and it solved the issue.

```
sudo rm -R /home/pi/RetroPie
sudo rm -R /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup
sudo rm -R /opt/retropie
sudo rm -R /home/pi/.emulationstation
sudo rm -R /usr/bin/emulationstation
sudo rm -R /etc/emulationstation
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem on 2 separate, new installs over several weeks.  Xserver starts up with Pixel, but then I'm taken back to TTY1.  I have to Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get back to it.  To reproduce, take new install of Raspbian Jesse + Pixel, then do "sudo apt-cache update && sudo apt-get upgrade".  Reboot.

Have you installed RetroPie by any chance?  I've compiled and installed retropie from the git repo on both installs.  It has its own boot options just like raspi-config, and I've considered that this behavior might be related.

Comment: I installed retro pie haven't tried removing it yet. It also started around the time I added a python script to rc. local but it persist even if I remove it