# Raspbian (Jessie) boots into tty7 then reverts into tty1

Tags: raspbian, retropie

So I installed Raspbian Jessie onto my Raspberry Pi 3 because I want to use RetroPie and Stretch doesn't support it yet. I installed Raspbian just fine, it boots and works as expected.

After that I went on to manually install RetroPie, and since that the following happens:

1. Raspbian boots into desktop - tty7, great.
2. Maybe 5 seconds after this, it automatically reverts to tty1 and I have to Ctrl + Alt + F7 back into desktop mode.

So far I have tried the following:

1. I have run raspi-config and within boot options have set it so it boots into Desktop without password, however this doesn't work.
2. I have run retropie_setup.sh and set the boot option to boot into desktop mode, this does not work.
3. Similarly, I have set emulationstation to run on boot, which works fine but then if I close out of emulation station, xserver is not running and I have to run startx to get a GUI.

Has anybody got any other ideas I can try please?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [After Boot Raspberry Pi Riverts to tty1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/66985/84497)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: edit the splashscreen shell script using

```
sudo sed -i 's/fbi -T 2/fbi -T 1/g' /opt/retropie/supplementary/splashscreen/asplashscreen.sh
```

You might have to do that again after updating RetroPie using `retropie_setup.sh` (I had to).

Background info: https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/10034/display-switch-from-pixel-to-tty1-after-manual-installation